# How to fix this issue in Recycler view?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

**I have a recycler view when clicked on the item VISIBLE hide seek bar for each item**.
the issue is when clicked on a single item then VISIBLE multiple hides seek bar and also when scrolling up down auto show randomly seek bar in this recycler view. help me. Thanks

[See in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/il3ab.jpg)

**Adapter class**

```
public class Adapter_Custom extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter_Custom.ViewHolder> {
    private Adapter_Custom.OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onImageClick(int position,ImageView imageView,SeekBar seekBar);
        void onSeekBarProgressChange(int position,String progress);

    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(Adapter_Custom.OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    Context MyContext;
    List<Model_main> modelList;

    public Adapter_Custom(Context myContext, List<Model_main> modelList) {
        MyContext = myContext;
        this.modelList = modelList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Adapter_Custom.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(MyContext);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rv_item_custom, null, false);
        return new Adapter_Custom.ViewHolder(view, mListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final Adapter_Custom.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Model_main model = modelList.get(position);
        holder.textView3.setText(model.getName());
        holder.sound_image.setImageResource(model.getImages());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return modelList.size();
    }
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView textView3;
        ImageView sound_image;
        SeekBar seekBar;


        public ViewHolder(@NonNull final View itemView, final Adapter_Custom.OnItemClickListener listener) {
            super(itemView);
            textView3 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            sound_image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sound_image);
            seekBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.seekBar);

            sound_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (listener != null) {
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                            listener.onImageClick(position,sound_image,seekBar);
//                            Toast.makeText(MyContext, ""+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
                    if (listener != null) {
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                            listener.onSeekBarProgressChange(position,String.valueOf(seekBar.getProgress()));
                        }
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                }
                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                }
            });

        }
    }
}
```

**ClickListner**

```
 adapter_custom1.setOnItemClickListener(new Adapter_Custom.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onImageClick(int position, ImageView imageView, SeekBar seekBar) {

                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    rv.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position).itemView.findViewById(R.id.seekBar)
                            .setVisibility(isVisible()? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);

//                    rv.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position).itemView.findViewById(R.id.seekBar).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//                    rv.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position).itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView3).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    if (custom_btn_div.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                        custom_btn_div.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:** Setting view visibility or checkbox check or `drawable` an `ImageView` to one or some of a `RecyclerView` items (rows).

**Solution:** You need to negate the opposite to remaining Views; e.g. If you set visiblity of a row item view to VISIBLE, then you've to make sure to set it as GONE/INVISIBLE to the similar items of the other rows.

**Reason:** Because the `RecyclerView`, as indicates from its name, recycles views; so if it needs to hold 100 items; and the screen size can hold 10 items at a time; then with the next scroll of the `RecyclerView` it doesn't create those items from the scrach, but copies the data of the new items into their place holds; if the data (visibility) is not set, then it takes the old data.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final Adapter_Custom.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Model_main model = modelList.get(position);
    holder.textView3.setText(model.getName());
    holder.sound_image.setImageResource(model.getImages());

    holder.seekBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: try..but issue when scrolled up and down auto seek bar hide

Comment: @MuhammadAfzal that is expected behavior .. you can solve this by having a boolean field for each row item (typically in your model class `Model_main`), that can have a default value of `false`, and set it for the clicked item in the `RecyclerView`; so you can then change `holder.seekBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);` into `holder.seekBar.setVisibility(model.getMyBoolean()? View.VISIBLE:View.GONE);` .. let me know if something not clear

Comment: Alternative solution: to have an integer in the RecyclerView adapter that holds the value of the row that you click; and then check with a condition before using `holder.seekBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);`